# Apache Beam - GroupByKey after Windowing using multiple keys?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm building a pipeline using Apache Beam Java SDK starting from [PubSubToBigQuery template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java) supplied by Google (the pipeline will be executed in Google Cloud Dataflow).

I'm using Windowing to aggregate data and save grouped data. For example:

```
1) a_id: 1 b_id: 2 c_id: 3 name: name1 value: 1
2) a_id: 1 b_id: 1 c_id: 3 name: name2 value: 1
3) a_id: 1 b_id: 2 c_id: 3 name: name3 value: 2
4) a_id: 1 b_id: 1 c_id: 3 name: name4 value: 1
5) a_id: 1 b_id: 1 c_id: 3 name: name5 value: 4
6) a_id: 2 b_id: 1 c_id: 3 name: name6 value: 1
```

I receive this block of data in my 1 minute Window, I want to group them by **a_id**, **b_id** and **c_id** and count rows, so I would expect this as aggregation result:

```
1) a_id: 1 b_id: 2 c_id: 3 count: 2
2) a_id: 1 b_id: 1 c_id: 3 count: 3
3) a_id: 2 b_id: 1 c_id: 3 count: 1
```

How can I use [GroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey) transform to make this kind of grouping? (With multiple keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the records you wish to aggregate have 3 part keys.  I am imagining a structure that contains:

- a_id
- b_id
- c_id
- name
- value

When you perform aggregation on your data, we aggregate by converting the records into Key/Value pairs (KV).

It is completely up to you how you choose to compose your keys.  To perform an aggregation as you desire, it would appear that we could create a key that is composed of the a_id, b_id and c_id fields.  Consider using a ParDo or Mapper to convert your records to have a key of "`[a_id]:[b_id]:[c_id]`" (or your own choice of unique key structure composed of your desired fields).

Comment: At the end I solved my problem just using template supplied by google without writing a new pipeline from scratch, but I check this answer as "accepted" since this is for sure the right way to proceed with this kind of problem.